# How to fire different setInterval functions at different moments of time?

Tags: javascript, scheduled-tasks, setinterval

Suppose I have

```
let boo = setInterval(() => console.log('boo'), 5000);
```

Suppose I want to add another interval function but I want to make sure it doesn't fire up at the same time:

```
let bla = setInterval(() => console.log('bla'), 5000);
```

Is there a way to check when is the first `boo` interval going to fire out and to make sure that `bla` happens, not at the same time, but, say, 2500 ms after the `boo`?

Comment: You can set up the first one and then `setTimeout` the setup of the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I want to make sure it doesn't fire up at the same time

It can't. JavaScript runs a single thread within the realm (loosely, page/tab). That thread does only one thing at a time, from beginning to end. So even if those timers fired at the same microsecond, the jobs to do those callbacks would go in the same queue, and they'd be processed one at a time by the thread.

If the work being done by the timer callback starts an asynchronous process, the second timer call can come in after the timer callback has started it (and returned) but while the asynchronous work is being done. If you want to prevent that, you'll have to do some manual synchronization between the two.

> Is there a way to check when is the first boo interval going to fire out and to make sure that bla happens, not at the same time, but, say, 2500 ms after the boo?

I'd probably do that by using a single timer:

```
let flag = true;
setInterval(() => {
    if (flag) {
        console.log("boo");
    } else {
        console.log("bla");
    }
    flag = !flag;
}, 2500);
```

Comment: It's actually in the context of node.js so do you think I'm better off using a scheduler module like `cron-node` to be able to retrieve the current task times and to check against them?

Comment: @DmitryParanyushkin - Node.js uses a single main thread just like browsers do, so the above is valid for it as well. But Node.js's `setInterval` is...very special, so yes, I would use something else. But the technique (fire every 2500ms and do one thing or the other) may still be the simplest solution.

Answer (score -1):

Call the set interval for bla in set timeout and provide time for 2500,

```js
let boo = setInterval(() => console.log('boo'), 5000);
setTimeout(()=>{
 let bla = setInterval(() => console.log('bla'), 5000);
 }, 2500);
```